# Mysterious vector operations

Tags: vectors, physics

My physics professor just gave this definition for vector multiplication and division that I can't corroborate anywhere:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} &= 9 \angle 37°\\
\mathbf{B} &= 3 \angle 20°\\
\mathbf{A} * \mathbf{B} &= |\mathbf{A}||\mathbf{B}|\angle(\theta_A + \theta_B) = 27\angle57°\\
\frac{\mathbf{A}}{\mathbf{B}} &= \frac{|\mathbf{A}|}{|\mathbf{B}|}\angle(\theta_A - \theta_B) = 3\angle17°
\end{align}
$$

My physics and multivariable calculus texts only mention the dot and cross product and explicitly don't define division. After several google and stack exchange searches turned up nothing, I'm here.

Also, if it helps identify the origin of these operations, the professor is an engineer.

Comment: These formulas are correct for multiplication and division of complex numbers A and B.  They aren't meaningful for vectors in $R^{n}$.

Comment: This is not an answer per se, but it's worth pointing out that in general there's no hope of defining division  and multiplication for vectors in a way that will be compatible with the norm. In fact, this can only be done in dimensions $1$, $2$, $4$, and $8$. This fact is known as Hurwitz's theorem. So in this case, your professor must be talking $2$ dimensional vectors. When equipped with a multiplication compatible with the norm, such vectors are also known as complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks. My professor hasn't made use of complex numbers in this class (first class of physics), so I'm not sure what he was getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are phasor notations.

In $A = M\angle{ (\omega t+ \theta)}$, $M$ is the amplitude and $\theta$ is the phase shift.

This can be equivalently written as $Me^{j(\omega t+\theta)}$, if angular frequency $\omega$ is considered.

So, let $A = 9\angle37^o = 9e^{j37^o}$

$B = 3\angle20^o = 3e^{j20^o}$

So,

> $$A\cdot B = 9e^{j37^o}3e^{j20^o} = 27 e^{j 57^o} = 27\angle57^o$$

Also,

> $$\frac{A}{B} = \frac{9e^{j37^o}}{3e^{j20^o}} = 3e^{j37^o -j20^o} =  3e^{j17^o} =3\angle17^o$$

Comment: Shouldn't $e^{20^\circ}$ be $e^{j 20^\circ}$?

Comment: Thanks@Spencer for pointing out!

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into what the use of these are in basic physics (kinematics).

Comment: You're welcome.